# Making a table that shows color of my custom built indicator on different timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have 2 different codes one that shows 200 Ema values(with color) in a table on different time frames and changes colour based on price.... Another code I have is of an EMA Band/channel that allows user to change input values also......                         I want to add another row to the table that shows EMA band color(green or red) for that particular timeframe chosen for 200 Ema table. I'm  providing the both codes below....

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5

// This script create Table for 200 EMA Values over Multi-Timeframe 

indicator(title="EMA", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true)

//TABLE INPUTS

PosTable = input.string(title="Position", defval="Bottom Right", options=["Top Right", "Middle Right", "Bottom Right", "Top Center", "Middle Center", "Bottom Center", "Top Left", "Middle Left", "Bottom Left"], group="Position & Size", inline="01")

SizTable = input.string(title="Size", defval="Small", options=["Auto", "Huge", "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"], group="Position & Size", inline="01")

Pos1Table=PosTable == "Top Right" ? position.top_right : PosTable == "Middle Right" ? position.middle_right : PosTable == "Bottom Right" ? position.bottom_right : PosTable == "Top Center" ? position.top_center : PosTable == "Middle Center" ? position.middle_center : PosTable == "Bottom Center" ? position.bottom_center : PosTable == "Top Left" ? position.top_left : PosTable == "Middle Left" ? position.middle_left : position.bottom_left

Siz1Table = SizTable == "Auto" ? size.auto : SizTable == "Huge" ? size.huge : SizTable == "Large" ? size.large : SizTable == "Normal" ? size.normal : SizTable == "Small" ? size.small : size.tiny

EMATable = table.new(Pos1Table, 7,2, bgcolor=#000000, frame_color=#4F4F4F, frame_width=2, border_color=#696969, border_width=1)

//200 EMA inputs

len = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length", inline="001", group="EMA200 inputs")

src = input.source(close, "Source", inline="002", group="EMA200 inputs")

//SELECTION OF TIMEFRAMES IN THE TABLES#

tf1 = input.timeframe("1",  "TF 1", inline="1", group="select timeframe")

tf2 = input.timeframe("5",  "TF 2", inline="3", group="select timeframe")

tf3 = input.timeframe("15", "TF 3", inline="5", group="select timeframe")

tf4 = input.timeframe("60", "TF 4", inline="1", group="select timeframe")

tf5 = input.timeframe("240","TF 5", inline="3", group="select timeframe")

tf6 = input.timeframe("1D", "TF 6", inline="5", group="select timeframe")

TF1  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, ta.ema(close, len))

TF5  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.ema(close, len))

TF15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf3, ta.ema(close, len))

TF60 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf4, ta.ema(close, len))

TF4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf5, ta.ema(close, len))

TF1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf6, ta.ema(close, len))

//PLOT EMA VALUES ABOUT THE CELLS

tfTxt(x)=>

    //adds abbreviation next to timeframe value

    out = x

    if not str.contains(x, "S") and not str.contains(x, "M") and 

       not str.contains(x, "W") and not str.contains(x, "D")

        if str.tonumber(x)%60 == 0

            out := str.tostring(str.tonumber(x)/60)+"H"

        else

            out := x + "m"

    out

f_fillCellText(_table, _column, _row, _value, _timeframe) =>

    //Default colors in table

    cell_color = #000000

    cell_txt   = #00000000

        

    //function to change cell and text colors based on LTP

    if _value >= close

        cell_color := #8B0000

        cell_txt := #FF8C00

    else if _value <= close

        cell_color := #006400

        cell_txt := #00FF00

    else

        cell_color := #1C1C1C

        cell_txt := #DCDCDC

    //

    _cellText = str.tostring(_value, '#') + '\n' + _timeframe

                                                                                                                                                               

    table.cell(EMATable, _column, _row, _cellText, bgcolor=color.new(cell_color, 40), text_color=cell_txt, text_size = Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 0, 0, "TF", text_color=#FFD700, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=size.small)

    table.cell(EMATable, 0, 1, "EMA ("+str.tostring(len)+")", text_color=#FFD700, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)table.cell(EMATable, 1, 0, tfTxt(tf1), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 2, 0, tfTxt(tf2), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 3, 0, tfTxt(tf3), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 4, 0, tfTxt(tf4), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 5, 0, tfTxt(tf5), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

    table.cell(EMATable, 6, 0, tfTxt(tf6), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)

if barstate.islast

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 1, 1, TF1,  "")

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 2, 1, TF5,  "")

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 3, 1, TF15, "")

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 4, 1, TF60, "")

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 5, 1, TF4H, "")

    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 6, 1, TF1D, "")

// EMA TABLE CODE END HERE
```

```
//@version=5

indicator("EMA band", overlay=true)

//INPUT

switchColor = input(true, "Color according to trend?")

visualSwitch  = input(true, title="Show as a Band?")

thicknesSwitch = input.int(1, title="Line Thickness", minval = 0)

transpSwitch = input.int(25, title="Band Transparency", step=5)

ema200Color = input.color(color.red, "EMA 200 Color")

// Calculate EMA of the low and high prices

// First EMA inputs

len1 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="EMA 1 Length")

src1 = input.source(close, title="EMA 1 Source")

// Second EMA inputs

len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="EMA 2 Length")

src2 = input.source(close, title="EMA 2 Source")

// Calculate EMAs

ema1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)

ema2 = ta.ema(src2, len2)

ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

// Calculate the difference between the two EMAs

band = ema1 - ema2

// Set the color of the band based on the relationship between the two EMAs

price_above_ema = close > ema1 and close > ema2

price_below_ema = close < ema1 and close < ema2

fill_color = price_above_ema ? color.rgb( 80, 175, 80,transpSwitch) : (price_below_ema ? color.rgb(250, 100, 100,transpSwitch) : color.new(color.gray, transpSwitch))

// Set the color of the EMAs based on the current price

ema1_color = close >= ema1 ? color.green : color.red

ema2_color = close >= ema2 ? color.green : color.red

/// Plot the EMAs and the band

plot(ema2, title='EMA 2', style=plot.style_line, color=ema1_color, linewidth=1)

plot(ema1, title='EMA 1', style=plot.style_line, color=ema2_color, linewidth=1)

plot(ema200, title='EMA 200', style=plot.style_line, color=ema200Color, linewidth=2)

//BandCOLOR

BandColor = switchColor ? fill_color : color.new(#ff9800, 50)

// Plot the band

Fi1 = plot(ema1, title="ema1", color=BandColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch)

Fi2 = plot(visualSwitch ? ema2 : na, title="ema2", color=BandColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch)

// Alert when the EMAs cross

alertcondition(ta.crossover(ema1,ema2), title='trending up.', message='trending up.')

alertcondition(ta.crossover(ema2, ema1), title=' trending down.', message=' trending down.')

// Fill the band

fill(Fi1, Fi2, title="Band Filler", color=fill_color)
//EMA BAND CODE END HERE
```

I know how to merger multiple built in indicator but don't know how to connect both of the indicator as one is customized. Please help review this code and find a solution, help is appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for. I created the band from the second code for each time frame the first code and then used and then added another row to the table showing the band value (ema1 - ema2) and color is the same as first code

```
//@version=5

// This script create Table for 200 EMA Values over Multi-Timeframe 

indicator(title="EMA", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true)

//TABLE INPUTS
PosTable = input.string(title="Position", defval="Bottom Right", options=["Top Right", "Middle Right", "Bottom Right", "Top Center", "Middle Center", "Bottom Center", "Top Left", "Middle Left", "Bottom Left"], group="Position & Size", inline="01")
SizTable = input.string(title="Size", defval="Small", options=["Auto", "Huge", "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"], group="Position & Size", inline="01")
Pos1Table=PosTable == "Top Right" ? position.top_right : PosTable == "Middle Right" ? position.middle_right : PosTable == "Bottom Right" ? position.bottom_right : PosTable == "Top Center" ? position.top_center : PosTable == "Middle Center" ? position.middle_center : PosTable == "Bottom Center" ? position.bottom_center : PosTable == "Top Left" ? position.top_left : PosTable == "Middle Left" ? position.middle_left : position.bottom_left
Siz1Table = SizTable == "Auto" ? size.auto : SizTable == "Huge" ? size.huge : SizTable == "Large" ? size.large : SizTable == "Normal" ? size.normal : SizTable == "Small" ? size.small : size.tiny
EMATable = table.new(Pos1Table, 7,3, bgcolor=#000000, frame_color=#4F4F4F, frame_width=2, border_color=#696969, border_width=1)

//200 EMA inputs
len = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length", inline="001", group="EMA200 inputs")
src = input.source(close, "Source", inline="002", group="EMA200 inputs")
len1 = input.int(21, minval=1, title="EMA 1 Length")
src1 = input.source(close, title="EMA 1 Source")
len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="EMA 2 Length")
src2 = input.source(close, title="EMA 2 Source")

//SELECTION OF TIMEFRAMES IN THE TABLES#
tf1 = input.timeframe("1",  "TF 1", inline="1", group="select timeframe")
tf2 = input.timeframe("5",  "TF 2", inline="3", group="select timeframe")
tf3 = input.timeframe("15", "TF 3", inline="5", group="select timeframe")
tf4 = input.timeframe("60", "TF 4", inline="1", group="select timeframe")
tf5 = input.timeframe("240","TF 5", inline="3", group="select timeframe")
tf6 = input.timeframe("1D", "TF 6", inline="5", group="select timeframe")
TF1  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, ta.ema(close, len))
TF5  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.ema(close, len))
TF15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf3, ta.ema(close, len))
TF60 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf4, ta.ema(close, len))
TF4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf5, ta.ema(close, len))
TF1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf6, ta.ema(close, len))


TF1EMA1  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF5EMA1  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF15EMA1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf3, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF60EMA1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf4, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF4HEMA1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf5, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF1DEMA1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf6, ta.ema(src1, len1))
TF1EMA2  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, ta.ema(src2, len2))
TF5EMA2  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.ema(src2, len2))
TF15EMA2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf3, ta.ema(src2, len2))
TF60EMA2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf4, ta.ema(src2, len2))
TF4HEMA2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf5, ta.ema(src2, len2))
TF1DEMA2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf6, ta.ema(src2, len2))

plot(TF1DEMA1)
plot(TF1DEMA2)
// Calculate the difference between the two EMAs
band1 = TF1EMA1 - TF1EMA2
band2 = TF5EMA1 - TF5EMA2
band3 = TF15EMA1 - TF15EMA2
band4 = TF60EMA1 - TF60EMA2
band5 = TF4HEMA1 - TF4HEMA2
band6 = TF1DEMA1 - TF1DEMA2

tfTxt(x)=>
    out = x
    if not str.contains(x, "S") and not str.contains(x, "M") and 
       not str.contains(x, "W") and not str.contains(x, "D")
        if str.tonumber(x)%60 == 0
            out := str.tostring(str.tonumber(x)/60)+"H"
        else
            out := x + "m"
    out

f_fillCellText(_table, _column, _row, _value, _timeframe) =>
    //Default colors in table
    cell_color = #000000
    cell_txt   = #00000000

    //function to change cell and text colors based on LTP
    if _value >= close
        cell_color := #8B0000
        cell_txt := #FF8C00
    else if _value <= close
        cell_color := #006400
        cell_txt := #00FF00
    else
        cell_color := #1C1C1C
        cell_txt := #DCDCDC
    _cellText = str.tostring(_value, '#') + '\n' + _timeframe                                                                                                                                                          
    table.cell(EMATable, _column, _row, _cellText, bgcolor=color.new(cell_color, 40), text_color=cell_txt, text_size = Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 0, 0, "TF", text_color=#FFD700, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=size.small)
    table.cell(EMATable, 0, 1, "EMA ("+str.tostring(len)+")", text_color=#FFD700, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 0, 2, "MA BAND", text_color=#FFD700, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 1, 0, tfTxt(tf1), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 2, 0, tfTxt(tf2), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 3, 0, tfTxt(tf3), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 4, 0, tfTxt(tf4), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 5, 0, tfTxt(tf5), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    table.cell(EMATable, 6, 0, tfTxt(tf6), text_color=#FFFFFF, text_size =Siz1Table)
    

if barstate.islast
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 1, 1, TF1,  "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 2, 1, TF5,  "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 3, 1, TF15, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 4, 1, TF60, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 5, 1, TF4H, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 6, 1, TF1D, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 1, 2, band1, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 2, 2, band2, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 3, 2, band3, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 4, 2, band4, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 5, 2, band5, "")
    f_fillCellText(EMATable, 6, 2, band6, "")
```